# prepareForSegue destination TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a button set to go to a TableViewController but decided I wanted to embed that TableViewController in a TabBarController. Well before I did this I had this bit of code in the previous ViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "showListSegue"){
        let des = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
        des.jsonfile = self.jsonfile
    }
}
```

Now when I try and click the button it give me this error.

> Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x111c818b0) to
>   'Forkit.TableViewController' (0x10d1b1490).

I tried the following code with no success as it gives me this error

> Value of type "UITabBarController" has no member 'jsonfile'.

```
 let des = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: You need to make the segue to point to the `TableViewController` instead of the `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 3):

The segue `showListSegue` now has your TabBarController as it's `destinationViewController`. This is why it can not cast it to `TableViewController`, because it's not the one you're looking for. The TabBarController does contain a reference to the ViewController you want though. You likely have two options:

**1: Use `.viewControllers` and find your view in there, like this:**

```
let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
let des = tabBarController.viewControllers![0]
```

In which [0] selects which tab's ViewController you need.

**2: Select the right tab and use `.selectedViewController`**

```
let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 // choose which tab is selected
let des = tabBarController.selectedViewController!
```

Please be aware that you are working with optional values here, so either be absolutely sure you can safely unwrap, or build in checks (casting with `as?` and `if let` statements, etc.).

More information: [UITabBarController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController)

Comment: How would I pass des.jsonfile = self.jsonfile to that then? I am getting this error. Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member jsonfile

Comment: I am trying to do this with a TableViewController

Comment: In that case you'd have to type cast: `let des = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! TableViewController`

Comment: Because, your custom class `TableViewController` is a `UIViewController`, but a special kind. It is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, which itself is a subclass of `UIViewController`. When you ask the tab bar controller for its viewControllers, it will give you an array of `UIViewController`, but this array can also contain those special cases like your `TableViewController`. That's when you have to type cast from one type to the other, in this case from 'UIViewController` to `TableViewController`, using `as?` or `as!`.

Answer (score -4):

Try This

```
 @IBAction func about(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("about", sender: sender)
}
```